# How to write php unit test

Tags: phpunit, unit-testing

I am having the below PHP class file. How do I create a TestCase or TestClass for this

```
<?php

class CRM_History_Page_HistoryPage extends CRM_Core_Page {

  public function run() {
    // Get User name from the contact id
    $query="select display_name from civicrm_contact where id={$_GET['cid']}";    
    $dao = CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery($query);
    $dao->fetch();
    $username=$dao->display_name;
    CRM_Utils_System::setTitle(ts("$username - Membership Periods"));

    $this->assign('periods',$this->getMembershipPeriod($_GET['membership_id'])); 
    parent::run();
  }
  public function getMembershipPeriod($membership_id) {

    $query="SELECT pr.start_date,pr.end_date, p.contribution_id,p.membership_id 
        FROM civicrm_membershipperiod pr 
        INNER JOIN civicrm_membership_payment p ON pr.membership_id= p.membership_id
        where p.membership_id=$membership_id";

 $query="SELECT pr.start_date,pr.end_date
        FROM civicrm_membershipperiod pr 
        where pr.membership_id=$membership_id";

    $dao = CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery($query);
    $i=0;$cid=$_GET['cid'];
    $validation_array=array();
    while ($dao->fetch()) {
      $data=[];
      $data['sno']=++$i;
      $data['start_date']=$dao->start_date;
      $data['end_date']=$dao->end_date;

//      $link="<a title='View Contribution' class='action-item crm-hover-button' href='./contact/view/contribution?reset=1&id=$contribution_id&cid=$cid&action=view&context=home&selectedChild=contribute'>Deatails</a>";

      $membership[]=$data;
  }

    return $membership;
  }
}
```

I have wrote a test class as below

```
<?php

use Civi\Test\HeadlessInterface;
use Civi\Test\HookInterface;
use Civi\Test\TransactionalInterface;



#use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

/**
 * @covers Email
 */
class CRM_History_Page_HistoryPageTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testCanBeCreatedFromRun()
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf(
            CRM_History_Page_HistoryPage::class,
            CRM_History_Page_HistoryPage::run(111)
        );
    }
}
```

But it gives the below error

```
root@mani-Lenovo-G560:/opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/membership.history# phpunit4 --bootstrap CRM/History/Page/HistoryPage.php tests/phpunit/CRM/History/TestClass.php

Fatal error: Class 'CRM_Core_Page' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/membership.history/CRM/History/Page/HistoryPage.php on line 3
root@mani-Lenovo-G560:/opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/membership.history#
```

Is there any dependency files missing